# Can't get to Windows after Ubuntu Thumbdrive install

Tags: boot

I did a thumb drive install of **kubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64** on my Windows 10 machine. Now, I cannot get to the Windows bootup when I restart the machine.

I can get into Ubuntu, and I can see all the external drives but not the C-drive on the machine. NOT a techie but experienced with Solaris and RH Linux, just not in a tech support role.

What do I check first? And then what?

Comment: Most likely you've wiped Windows from your disk. Pleas add the steps you took when installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that you can do, just going off of what information that you have provided:

1) If you have installed Ubuntu correctly, alongside Windows (used the "install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option in the installer) when you installed, try booting into Ubuntu, updating your system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` and then running `sudo update-grub2`.

2) You could also try to boot into Windows by pressing whatever the F key button is to select your "boot options" (mine is F9 on my Dell laptop), while booting. Then at the boot options screen, if Windows is there, select it.

If neither option 1) and 2) work, then something may have been done wrong during installation, or something WENT wrong during the installation.

Cheers, and let us know how it goes!

Comment: both commands worked and here is the outout.

Comment: both commands worked. saved output.                                                                                                                          
F12 is my boot options and it returns Ubuntu but not Win. Thats the problem. will restart machine now